# Appending Rich Text Style

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotusscript

From a button click event I wish to add a 'time stamp' with user name into the body of a rich text item, ie log the time and the user for new updates in the field. For some reason the style is not applied.

I have a further problem due to the requirement to close and open the document on RT items in that the cursor returns to the top of the field rather than the bottom I don't believe there is solution for that though?

Any help is appreciated

```
Function TimeStampBold(fieldname As String)

Dim session As New NotesSession
Dim workspace As New NotesUIWorkspace
Dim uidocNew As NotesUIDocument
Dim rti As NotesRichTextItem
Dim rtiStyle As NotesRichTextStyle


set uidoc = workspace.currentdocument
uidoc.Refresh True
Set doc = uidoc.Document
Set rti = doc.Getfirstitem(fieldname)
Set rtiStyle = session.CreateRichTextstyle()
rtiStyle.Bold = True
rtiStyle.Fontsize=8
Print  rtiStyle.Bold '                  Returns True
Call rti.AppendStyle(rtiStyle)          Style is not applied.

If (Len(uidoc.FieldGetText("Body"))) = 0 Then
Call rti.AppendText  (Format$ (Now(), "d-mmm-yy h:mm"))
    Else
Call rti.Addnewline(2)
Call rti.AppendText  (Format$ (Now(), "d-mmm-yy h:mm"))
End If
Call rti.AppendText  (" " & session.CommonUserName &" - ")
rtiStyle.Bold=False
Call rti.Appendstyle(rtistyle)

rti.Update
doc.SaveOptions ="0"
Call uidoc.Close(True)
Set uidocNew = workspace.EditDocument(True, doc,,,,True)
uidocNew.Document.Removeitem("SaveOptions")
uidocNew.GotoField(fieldname)
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will work, but perhaps you can set a hidden field in the document to '1' and put some code in the PostOpen event script to check that field, and do the gotoField call if it the value is '1'. (And reset the field value back to '0' in the PostOpen, too.)

Comment: Sorry Richard I don't understand, my first problem is the AppendStyle doesn't work. There is a second problem in that the cursors returns to the top of the (say) Body field. I didn't raise a second question for that as I don't think it is possible to return it to the bottom.
I'm not sure what the purpose of a hidden field is.

Comment: I didn't read carefully enough. All I saw was the second problem. I don't see a reason why the style wasn't applied. As for the hidden field, its only purpose was to serve as a flag that the PostOpen can look at when it executes following your call to EditDocument. Was thinking that you could execute the GotoField there, but actually that won't get you to the end either. Had originally been thinking you would have to do a GotoField to the next field following Body and use Windows API calls to tab backwards to the end of the Body, but I lost that train of thought somewhere along the way.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem may be that you are changing the rtiStyle.Bold to false before calling rti.update.

Personally, I would create two rtiStyles: one bold and one not.  You can create these up front and apply them where you want without modifying the same style after it has been applied.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Rob, unfortunately that doesn't work. Strangly if I append a new line before I append the style it does work. On my second point, getting the cursor to the bottom, my button for the script is just below the rtf so I added a 1point 'cursor' field next to the button so the user doesn't really see it then used a uidoc.GotoFiled("Curso") at the end and which the gives the impression that you are at the bottom of the rtf. Whole solution is very old, messy and dated but that's all we have AFAIK

Comment: Pleased you got sorted @MarkMaden.  Notes can be a peculiar beast at times.